# How can I force the text go to the button of the panel?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, text, alignment

At the moment I have the following code which works fine.

```
label = new JLabel(panelLabel,SwingConstants.CENTER);
outputPanel.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I get the text in the center of the panel (in terms of the left-right position as well as in terms of the top-bottom).

Now I want to set the position to the bottom (and center in terms of "left-right"). I tried to use SOUTH instead of the CENTER in the first line. Compiler does not complains but during the execution i get `IllegalArgumentException: HorizontalAlignment`. What is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JLabel constructor you are using is `JLabel(String label, int horizontalAlignement)`.

As defined in the [javadoc](http://tinyurl.com/y92yxdd), this int should be only in certain values:

> **JLabel public JLabel(String text, int horizontalAlignment)**
>   Creates a JLabel instance with the
>   specified text and horizontal
>   alignment. The label is centered
>   vertically in its display area.
>
> *Parameters:*
>   text - The text to be displayed by the label.
>   **horizontalAlignment - One of the following constants defined in SwingConstants: LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT, LEADING or TRAILING.**

This value sets where your text is aligned, **inside** the JLabel. You can't use "SOUTH" here, and this is why you get the "InvalidArgument" exception.

---

If you want to make your text on the bottom of the label, you have to use [setVerticalAlignment(int)](http://tinyurl.com/y8ggha3), with `Swingconstants.BOTTOM`. That supposes that your label is centered and will potentially take a wide height on your panel.

If you use a BorderLayout for this panel, you might want to try to add your label with `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, as hint for the layout manager. This will stick the label to the bottom part, and it will have a minimal height (the one necessary to display the text). In this case, the vertical alignment of the text doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

What layout manager did you use for `outputPanel` ?
Did you try

```
outputPanel.add(label,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

?

Had you set outputPanel's layout manager to `BorderLayout`, you would not get this error.
There is nothing wrong as far as I can see.

Comment: For the outputPanel I use BorderLayout. The "cell" with the text is added to the correct place I just wanted to have the text in the correct position of the cell. But I just realized that I do not know where my "cell" ends and begins. So, my be the text is on the bottom.

Comment: Are you still getting the IllegalArgumentException: HorizontalAlignment exception? 
If not set border to your label as        
label.setBorder(LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder());

and it will show you where your "cell" ends and begins.

Comment: read again his question, he was using SwingConstants.SOUTH in the **first** line, not in the second.

Comment: @Gnoupi
Good catch. I was too quick to jump to conclusion.